# Encuesta para que Alumnos de una escuela evaluen a sus maestros

Tags: html

Tengo un código con el cual pretendo hacer una evaluacion docente. Necesito que los usuarios sean capaces de seleccionar solamente una calificación para cada nombre y no varias como en el siguiente ejemplo con "juan hernandez".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código que tengo

```
 <table class="table table-bordered">
 <tr>
   <th>Docente</th>
   <th>1</th>
   <th>2</th>
   <th>3</th>
   <th>4</th>
   <th>5</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>';
// $mostrando_docentes=mysqli_fetch_array($mostrar_maestros);
 while ($mostrando_docentes=mysqli_fetch_array($mostrar_maestros)) {
   echo '<td>'.$mostrando_docentes['Nombre']." ".$mostrando_docentes['ApellidoP']." ".$mostrando_docentes['ApellidoM'].'</td>       

   <td><input type="radio" name="respuesta"  ></td>


   <td><input type="radio" name="respuesta1" ></td> 

   <td><input type="radio" name="respuesta2" ></td>

   <td><input type="radio" name="respuesta3" ></td>

   <td><input type="radio" name="respuesta4" ></td>

 </tr>

 ';}echo'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que cada radio button el nombre que tienen es distinto en el mismo profesor por ende se podrán seleccionar varios, para corregir esto, en la linea para obtener los docentes `$mostrando_docentes=mysqli_fetch_array($mostrar_maestros);` podrías obtener el id de cada maestro y llamar los radio buttons con ese id, para que por cada maestro sea diferente, en código sería algo así:

```
<?php
$mostrando_docentes=mysqli_fetch_array($mostrar_maestros);
while ($mostrando_docentes=mysqli_fetch_array($mostrar_maestros)) {
   echo '<tr><td>'.$mostrando_docentes['Nombre']." ".$mostrando_docentes['ApellidoP']." ".$mostrando_docentes['ApellidoM'].'</td>';?>       

   <td><input type="radio" name="docente_<?php echo $mostrando_docentes['idDocente'];?>"  ></td>


   <td><input type="radio" name="docente_<?php echo $mostrando_docentes['idDocente'];?>" ></td> 

   <td><input type="radio" name="docente_<?php echo $mostrando_docentes['idDocente'];?>" ></td>

   <td><input type="radio" name="docente_<?php echo $mostrando_docentes['idDocente'];?>" ></td>

   <td><input type="radio" name="docente_<?php echo $mostrando_docentes['idDocente'];?>" ></td>

 </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Gracias Juan, estare trabajando en base a esto... aun estoy teniendo detallitos pero espero poder arreglarlos, nuevamente gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Tienes que crear un conjunto de radios para cada respuesta, todos con el mismo nombre y su respectivo valor, porque así es como funciona, ejemplo:

```
<td><input type="radio" name="respuesta" value="1"></td>
<td><input type="radio" name="respuesta" value="2"></td>
<td><input type="radio" name="respuesta" value="3"></td>
<td><input type="radio" name="respuesta" value="4"></td>
<td><input type="radio" name="respuesta" value="5"></td>
```

Así solo podrás seleccionar una opción en cada línea. El problema es que no puedes repetir el nombre para los demás docentes, vas a tener que hacer algo como:

```
<?php
// Supongamos que ya asignaste id de docenta a la variabla $id
for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    echo "<td><input type=\"radio\" name=\"respuesta-$id\" value=\"$i\"></td>\n";
}
```

Con eso tendras un juego de radios para cada docente y solo se podrá seleccionar una opción. Para saber cómo manejarlos al procesar el formulario usa **var_dump($_POST);** y ahí verás las respuestas.

Answer (score 1):

El problema lo tienes en tus radio buttons, los radio buttons debes definirles el mismo nombre y agregarles su respectivo valor:

```
  <tr>  
   <td><input type="radio" name="respuesta" value ="respuesta1" ></td>     
   <td><input type="radio" name="respuesta" value ="respuesta2" ></td>    
   <td><input type="radio" name="respuesta" value ="respuesta3" ></td>    
   <td><input type="radio" name="respuesta" value ="respuesta4" ></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>   
   <td><input type="radio" name="respuesta1" value ="respuesta1" ></td>     
   <td><input type="radio" name="respuesta1" value ="respuesta2" ></td>    
   <td><input type="radio" name="respuesta1" value ="respuesta3" ></td>    
   <td><input type="radio" name="respuesta1" value ="respuesta4" ></td>
 </tr>
```

Si la respuesta soluciona tu problema, no olvides dejar tu voto e indicar si te fue útil.

Comment: Andres..... Intentandolo de esta manera me sale un resultado parecido a este, me gustaria seguir teniendo tu apoyo o poder contactarte para ello

http://imgur.com/IOomHta

Comment: @uzzielsánchezdíaz, solo es cuestion de borrar un <td> para que ya no tengas 5 opciones si no, solo una, ya actualice mi respuesta.

Comment: De igual manera lo intente a si pero simplemente me borra una columna de radiobuttons

Answer (score 0):

Revisando tu código veo que mantienes nombres diferentes, cuando se usa input radio, estos se agrupan por nombres, es decir, que solo se podran seleccionar entre aquellos que mantengan el mismo nombre (name).

Un ejemplo:

```html
<form> <p>Check the languages you are most proficient in.</p> <input type="radio" name="chooseone" value="HTML"><label for="HTML"> HTML</label><br> <input type="radio" name="chooseone" value="CSS"><label for="CSS"> CSS</label><br> <input type="radio" name="chooseone" value="JS"><label for="JS"> JS</label><br> <input type="radio" name="chooseone" value="PHP"><label for="PHP"> PHP</label><br> <input type="radio" name="chooseone" value="Ruby"><label for="Ruby"> Ruby</label><br> <input type="radio" name="chooseone" value="INTERCAL"><label for="INTERCAL"> INTERCAL</label><br> </form>
```

Comment: Creo que quedaria mejor si usaras de ejemplo la versión de uzziel